# A self join query

Tags: sql

Given this relational schema

- people (pid, name, gender, age, email, city, state)
- books (ISBN, title, edition, publisher, year, rating)
- write (pid, ISBN) pid is a foreign key and refers to people (pid), ISBN is a foreign key and refers to books (ISBN)

I need to write a SQL query to find the authors who either never published co-authored books or only co-authored with others from the same state, return their names.

I know I need to use a self join but not sure how to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Tim's reasoning is correct, but the query is not.  It requires a self-join on `writes`:

```
select p.*
from people p
where not exists (select 1
                  from writes w join
                       writes w2
                       on w.isbn = w2.isbn join
                       people p2
                       on w2.pid = w.pid
                  where w.pid = p.pid and
                        p.state <> p2.state
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two logical criteria can actually be condensed into saying that you only want authors who have *not* coauthored books with other from *different* states.  So, we can write a query for that:

```
SELECT p1.name
FROM people p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM write w INNER JOIN people p2 ON p2.pid = w.pid
                  WHERE w.pid = p1.pid AND p2.state <> p1.state);
```

Comment: I feel that books should be included as well

Comment: Why?  Your logic does not actually involve any of the book fields.  Rather, we only need to know that such an `ISBN` exists and is associated with a certain author.

Comment: Right but you did not include ISBN in you answere.

Comment: You said: `return their names` ... you did not mention any other fields.  If you require other fields, then you should mention this.

Comment: But what does it mean to co author ? They must share the same ISBN I guess.

Comment: @Tomer The `books` table is what is known as a _junction_ table.  It stores relationships between authors and their books (and ISBN is guaranteed to always be unique).  So, if we find that two authors are related to the _same_ ISBN, then it implies that they are co-authors...right?